# No phone emulator showing in device list in visual studio 2015 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, win-universal-app, emulation, windows-10-mobile

So I would like to test some apps on windows phone 10, but there is no emulator to choose from in the device drop down. I clicked on the 'Download new emulators...' option in the dropdown, downloaded the package, and installed a 3.5GB windows phone 10 emulator but I'm not seeing where it went. I've restarted windows and opened up the test project in VS2015 CE. Still no emulator available.

Anyone else have this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: is Hyper-V installed? This is required to run the phone emulator

Comment: Yes, hyper-v is installed

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to switch the *platform* in your Visual Studio from **ARM** to **x86**.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Also: weird.

Comment: Why he needs to switch the platform from ARM to x86?

Comment: I must say that also in VS 2017 this resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but have you checked that your system meets all the requirements for running the emulator as described [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=532763)?

Note that your hardware must support features like DEP and SLAT **and** the BIOS must have those features turned on.

Comment: Installer checks these conditions, doesn't it?

Comment: @CSharper the installer _may_ check for some (or all) of these conditions but even if it does, conditions may change.  For example a user may modify BIOS settings after the installer ran successfully.  That said, the accepted answer makes clear that my guess was wrong.