# Visual Studio 2015 Emulator for Android not visible for debugging

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I recently started working with visual studio 2015, and I wanted to test the new features. I have vs2015 with vs emulator installed. i can start an emulator and it starts up fine. adb.exe says there is an emulator on

```
C:\..\..>adb.exe devices
List of devices attached
169.254.76.233:5555     device
emulator-5554   device
```

but visual studio 2015 does not see it so i cant use the emulator. When i start an emulator via AVD Manager.exe it is visible in visual studio same goes for my phone.

I was wondering what could be the problem?

Comment: apparently i was not looking right. The emulator is x86 so if the debugger is set to ARM it will not show the emulator. Problem solved.

Comment: I had the same problem but found this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031556/no-phone-emulator-showing-in-device-list-in-visual-studio-2015-rtm

Answer (score -4):

In Visual Studio 2015, go to Tools > Options > Cross-Platform, and make sure the Android SDK path is the same as your path to ADB. If not, check the box and change the SDK path to match the location of the Android SDK you are using.